# Running a method on click from a child component slot?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a third part component that accepts a slot, inside this slot I want to place an input like so:

```
<input type="text" @click="this.run">
```

The issue I am having is this logs:

```
Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined
```

On my parent component where I use the third party component I have the method set up:

```
methods: {

    run() {
        console.log('run');
    },
},
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try without `this` and your method as `run: function () {...}`

Comment: puelo - that worked but why?

Comment: Either vue-js matches methods by name, or the `this` puts the method call into the wrong scope. Either way i don't think you ever need put `this` on any of the event handlers.

Comment: `run ()  {}`  is perfectly allowed statement in `ES6`. So as long as you have the transpiler set  correctly you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template will get compile into a render method.
So you should not use `this` as it will be implicit.

```
 <input type="text" @click="run">
```

Should work fine